# Change click behavior in list with checkboxes

Tags: html, css

I have a list of checkboxes and color pickers with some text associated to it. 
Before I added the color pickers I was able to check a checkbox when I clicked on the text next to it (I don't know how).
Now when I click on the text it trigger the color picker instead.
I would like to understand what makes this behavior and how to change it.

Html :

```
<br><div id="cb">
        <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
              <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
                Buffer overflow
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
              <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="62,63">
                Diffusion enabled/disabled
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
                <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="8,9,10,11">
                Diffusion programs edit
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
                <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="64,65,66,67">
                Diffusion programs suppress
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
                 <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="50,54">
                Diffusion start/stop
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
                <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="68,69">
                Empty Reserve 1/2
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="76">
                Flow rate alarm
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="21,22,23">
                GSM module events
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="16,17">
                Input pressure over/underflow
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="18,19">
                Output pressure over/underflow
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="200,201">
                Polling events
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4,5">
                Power back/Power failure
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="26,27">
                Reserves pressure check
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="70,71">
                Reserves refill
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="59">
                Reserve switch
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR" >
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="30">
                Setup parameter change
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
          <input type="color" id="CLR">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="28,29">
                UPC mode adjust/check
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header {
  height: 8rem;
  background: #009688;
}

.content {
  width: 20rem;
  margin: -4rem auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.3125rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#CLR {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
#CLR::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;   
}
#CLR::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


.list {
  margin: .5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list__item {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.label--checkbox {
  position: relative;
  margin: .5rem;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 135%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.375rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border: 1.5px solid #c1c1c1;
}
.checkbox:checked:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: .5rem;
  border-color: #009688;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}
.checkbox:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.1rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button--round {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s background ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s background ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s background ease-in-out;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: #5677fc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.3125rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.button--round i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 220%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button--round:hover {
  background: #3b50ce;
}

.button--sticky {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 16rem;
}

.content {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-name: slideUp;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6.25rem);
    transform: translateY(6.25rem);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6.25rem);
    transform: translateY(6.25rem);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

*Note: I don't want to change the order between the colorpicker and the checkbox.*

[SQL Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeNRM/268/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.header {
  height: 8rem;
  background: #009688;
}

.content {
  width: 20rem;
  margin: -4rem auto 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.3125rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#CLR {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
#CLR::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0; 
}
#CLR::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


.list {
  margin: .5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list__item {
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.label--checkbox {
  position: relative;
  margin: .5rem;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 135%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.375rem;
  margin: 0 1rem 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox:before {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border: 1.5px solid #c1c1c1;
}
.checkbox:checked:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: .5rem;
  border-color: #009688;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
}
.checkbox:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.125rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.1rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button--round {
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s background ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s background ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s background ease-in-out;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: #5677fc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.3125rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.button--round i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 220%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button--round:hover {
  background: #3b50ce;
}

.button--sticky {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2rem;
  top: 16rem;
}

.content {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
  animation-name: slideUp;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6.25rem);
    transform: translateY(6.25rem);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6.25rem);
    transform: translateY(6.25rem);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<br><div id="cb">
        <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">
          
              <input type="color" id="CLR">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1">
                Buffer overflow
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list__item">
          
              <input type="color" id="CLR">
          <label class="label--checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="62,63">
                Diffusion enabled/disabled
          </label>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Just change the position of label after the color picker

```
<li class="list__item">
  <input type="color" id="CLR">
  <label class="label--checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="28,29">
     UPC mode adjust/check
   </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Oh ok I understand it was about the label, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was the way you declared your ArrayAdapter

instead of doing like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    R.layout.list_item, R.id.single_item, listContent);
```

use this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent);
```

EDIT:

For custom adapter behavior, you'd have to make your own Adapter.

You could then add onCheckedChangedListener for the checkbox and onClickListener for the item click.

Comment: I think you may have answered to the wrong question